# Integrate ADFS with SAML 2.0 Response

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, saml, saml-2.0, adfs

Currently I am integrating SharePoint environment with a Entitlement system which sends their Response in SAML 2.0 notation.

I used ADFS as the Middle person and tried to transform the SAML response to a format which is compatible to SharePoint. ultimately ADFS serves as the Relying party for Sharepoint.

The Notation Entitlement System SAML response is in the Following Format.

```
         <saml:Attribute AttributeName="email" AttributeNamespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                    <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">testuser@ABS.com</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
```

Any help on the integration process will be a Great Help.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want the email attribute to be transformed to?

Comment: I tried to integrate to SharePoint directly to SAML 2.0. But it does not authenticate the user. Checked with Fiddler the response SharePoint gets. It conains a SAML response like this. So sharepoint understands when we get the response in the following format."http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"